# How to make manifest available for a generic type in scala?

Tags: scala, generics, generic-programming, json4s

Given a scala http client being parsed through json4s, I had the following working code to transform a Future of a HttpResponse into a Future of a case class:

```
  def getJobIds(): Future[Seq[Job]] = {
    ... 
    var req = HttpRequest(
      method = HttpMethods.GET,
      uri = uri
    )

    val res: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(req)

    res.flatMap {
      case response@HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, _, _) => {
        val buffer = ByteString("")

        response.entity.dataBytes
          .runFold(buffer)(_ ++ _)
          .map(_.utf8String)
          .map(
            (body: String) => {
              parse(body).as[Seq[Job]]
            }
          )
      }
      case _: Any => throw new Throwable("Error!")
    }
  }
```

Now I wanted to extract the logic to transform the HttpResponse to a case classes using generics in order to not repeat myself for other calls:

```
  def getJobIds(): Future[Seq[Job]] = {
    ...
    val res: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(req)
    transformResponse[Seq[Job]](res)
  }

  private def transformResponse[T](r: Future[HttpResponse]): Future[T] = {
    r.flatMap {
      case response@HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, _, _) => {
        val buffer = ByteString("")

        response.entity.dataBytes
          .runFold(buffer)(_ ++ _)
          .map(_.utf8String)
          .map(parse(_).extract[T])
      }
      case _: Any => throw new Throwable("Error!")
    }
  }
```

Yet this now throws:

```
 Metronome.scala:46:32: No Manifest available for T
```

for the line

```
.map(parse(_).extract[T])
```

How do I make the code work with the use of generics?

Answer (score 4):

The issues comes from json4s `extract` method.

If you look it up you'll find that its defintion is:

```
  def extract[A](implicit formats: Formats, mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]): A =
    Extraction.extract(jv)(formats, mf)
```

For some reason, the implicit Manifest look-up works for the concrete type, yet for the generic case you'll have to define the implicit manifest for your `T` type:

```
  private def transformResponse[T](r: Future[HttpResponse])
                                  (implicit ev: scala.reflect.Manifest[T]): Future[T] = {
    r.flatMap {
      case response@HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, _, _) => {
        val buffer = ByteString("")

        response.entity.dataBytes
          .runFold(buffer)(_ ++ _)
          .map(_.utf8String)
          .map(parse(_).extract[T])
      }
      case _: Any => throw new Throwable("Error!")
    }
```

Now your code will compile and run.